# How to validate source code against custom rule? (absence of "DANGER" string in code)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I always add `// DANGER` comments when writing debug statements that I know I *must* remove before building the next release of my Android app.

So before building each release, I manually do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for `"DANGER"` and make sure no debug statement is still there.

I might forget this someday so I would like to automate this last part: release build should simply fail (preferrably immediately) if the code contains `"DANGER"`.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Custom lint rule? Custom gradle task?

Comment: Revise each commit for the repository and dont commit then, then to generate a build do a git stash before generating, than git stash pop to receive your non production changes back

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I am looking for an automated step integrated in the build process. What you suggest is manual, and actually sounds even less practical than my current manual process.

Comment: Of course it is, but you should NEVER commit debug code into repository

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Fair enough. I forgot to mention that I usually do the last commit *after* the release build, so the repo usually doesn't contain debug code.

Comment: you can commit local, stash undesired changes generate build then stash pop back, then push changes

Comment: But you need to use a good tool like 'git gui' on windows/linux or 'wish' on mac and commit only valid lines

Comment: if you can be bothered, i *think* you can write a custom lint rule to detect your `DANGER`s and report an error (hence stopping the compilation for your release build). Personally, I'm happy with searching the codebase for a custom string (like your DANGER).

Answer (score 0):

Write `// TODO: somethign` and use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for Java files. You could also use `// TODO:` and use [Detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) for Kotlin files.

Writing a custom Gradle task or a custom Lint Rule also seem perfectly valid but given that there are tools out there that already do this and much more, I'd choose one of these.